# AWS Elastic Beanstalk REST API - Auth params?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've just started working with the AWS Java SDK and need to deploy/update an elastic beanstalk application from my application. Currently, I have only found [documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CreateApplicationVersion.html) for a REST api that allows the creation of an application version. As with the rest of Amazon's REST api, authentication is needed with a menagerie of [params](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/CommonParameters.html). The docs on ELB don't have specifics on authentication, whereas the docs for S3/EC2 have plenty of explanation.

I am specifically asking about the "Signature Version" parameter? Does anybody have an idea of what that would be for the ELB REST api? Could anybody that has successfully worked with the ELB API point in the right direction for authentication? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Use the source](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java), luke. In particular, those versions are bound to a specific version ([see this announcement](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1399) for an idea)

All the AWS Services keep a common core. In particular, besides the Beanstalk-API specific part, you need to know the common part of the AWS apis, which are described [in this document](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html))

Comment: I went to the repo, looked around, didn't see anything pertaining to the **REST API** for Elastic-Beanstalk. Sorry Obi-Wan, your mind has been clouded...lol

Comment: Oh, now I understood (silly: why you just don't use the AWS SDK anyway?)

Comment: No, the AWS SDK supports that since 2011. I know because thats what we've already had when I decided to write my Maven Plugin for it (beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br) ;)